# How to change background color of menu to transparent?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a menu and want to change background colour to transparent in desktop view.

```css
ul.dropdown-menu li  {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
  <ul id="menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-1496" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item- object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-19 current_page_item menu-item-has-   children menu-item-1496 dropdown active">
  <a title="Home" href="https://adsler.co.uk/">Home </a>
  <span class="dropdown-toggle shapely-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </span>
    <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu"
    <li id="menu-item-1502" class="fa fa-user menu-item menu-item-type- post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1502">
    <a title="Create 
    Adsler Account" href="https://adsler.co.uk/create-account/">Create Adsler Account</a>
    </li>
```

Doesn't work.....

Comment: What template are you using? Or can you add the existing css?

Comment: Please take the time and make an effort ( small effort ) to share tidy code and valid code. Second, the `background-color` is on the `ul` or the `li` . In the question you say you want to change the color of the menu. That is the `ul`. But you change the `background-color` of the menu items `li`

Comment: use media query to trigger change on different screen resolution

Answer (score 0):

Use a media query to target the screen size that you consider to be for a desktop.

For instance:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1028px) {
  ul.dropdown-menu li  {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

This will target medias of type 'screen' and for viewport sizes of minimum '1028px' in width. You will need to experiment with the min-width size yourself.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your HTML seems to be invalid: The second (inner) ul starting tag is simply not closed.
2. If you want to make the menu transparent, you should put your rule on the "ul" tag, not on the "li" tag, like this:

   ul.dropdown-menu {
     background-color: transparent !important;
   }

Answer (score 0):

```
.main-navigation .menu > li ul { 
    padding: 10px; 
    right: 0 !important; 
    background-color: transparent;  
    border-color:
    transparent;box-shadow: none
}
.main-navigation .menu > li > ul > 
li { 
    display: flex; 
    align-items: center; 
    background- color:transparent;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to tackle the issue of targeting only desktop view. You've also got some badly formatted and broken CSS here.